# Why is my jQuery selector not returning any elements?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Given the following HTML:

```
<table>     
    <tbody>     
        <tr data-week="0">
            <td class="timeSlot" data-day="0" data-timeslotid="0"></td>
            <td class="timeSlot" data-day="0" data-timeslotid="1"></td>
            <td class="timeSlot" data-day="0" data-timeslotid="2"></td>
            <td class="timeSlot" data-day="0" data-timeslotid="3"></td>
            <td class="timeSlot" data-day="0" data-timeslotid="4"></td>
            <td class="timeSlot" data-day="1" data-timeslotid="0"></td>
            <td class="timeSlot" data-day="1" data-timeslotid="1"></td>
            <td class="timeSlot" data-day="1" data-timeslotid="2"></td>
            <td class="timeSlot" data-day="1" data-timeslotid="3"></td>
            <td class="timeSlot" data-day="1" data-timeslotid="4"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

and script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var week = $("table tbody tr[data-week='0']");
    var dayTimeSlots = $(".timeSlot[data-day='0']", week);
    console.log($(dayTimeSlots).length);  // <-- Gives me 5
    var timeSlot = $("[data-timeslotid='1']", dayTimeSlots);
    console.log($(timeSlot).length);  // <-- Gives me 0??

    var temp = $("[data-timeslotid='1']", week);
    console.log($(temp).length);  // <-- gives me 2
});
```

Why can't I get this single element from my jQuery subset?

This is a dumbed down example, but in my code I have approx 500,000 td elements and I need to filter it down to the narrowest subset I can for performance reasons.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wp36nLnw/4/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is because the contextual selector that you're currently using:

```
var timeSlot = $("[data-timeslotid='1']", dayTimeSlots);
```

Is the equivalent of using `find()`. This means that it's looking for elements with the `data-timeslotid` attribute as children of those in the `dayTimeSlots` object. Instead, you need to use `filter()` to reduce the matched set based on the selector provided. Try this:

```
var timeSlot = dayTimeSlots.filter("[data-timeslotid='1']");
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/wp36nLnw/6/)